# How do I parse a HTML string to DOM with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to parse html string

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>....<some tag></some tag>...<script>    </script></body></html>
```

How can I do this?

Code:

```
<iframe id="FileFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<script>
var doc = document.getElementById('FileFrame').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>....<some tag></some tag>...<script></script></body></html>');
doc.close();
</script>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Your **first step** should always be to [look in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/).

Comment: It's not static html, its always different.

Comment: @Geha - what's that got to do with anything?

Comment: I nead to build dom to insert in iframe. I tried many options but i alwayes get the same result or its not displaying all web pages or it converts it without styles and scripts

Answer (score 1):

Simply using the jQuery function will do that for you.

```
var myHtml = "<html><body><b>Some Text</b></body></html>";
var myDocument = $(myHtml);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's display page without styles

Comment: If you're rendering it in an iFrame, any styles within the code, whether it's inline or not, should show. What have you tried? Would be nice if you could update your question with code you've tried already so we have a better understanding.

Comment: I updated the question.